# If $a,b,c \in \mathbb {Z}, a=bc, p \mid a$, but $p^2 \nmid a$, then precisely one of $b, c$ is divisible by $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Unable to work it out in any better way, as the only approach that can think of is:

The terms $b,c$ are possibly composite, prime or co-prime. In any case, if $p \mid a$, then exactly one factor (either $b$ or $c$) is divided. To divide by $p^2$, need that either one of $b,c$ is divisible by $p^2$, or both $b$ and $c$ are divisible by $p$.

Hence, if $p^2 \nmid a$, then precisely one of $b, c$ is divisible by $p$.

Request a better, more polished approach, if correct.

Comment: You mean $b$ and $c$  is divisible by $p$.

Comment: Yes, as $a = bc$ is divisible by $p$, so obviously.

Comment: If $p$ is a prime  and $p\mid bc$, then $p|\mid b$ or $p\mid c$.It is obvious fact.

Comment: I don't understand question :)

Comment: Need a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know from $p$ being prime that $p | bc$ implies $p$ divides at least one of $b,c$.

Now suppose $p | b$ and $p | c$.  Then immediately $p^2 | a$. By contrapositive, since we assume $p^2 \nmid a$, we see $p$ divides at most one of $b,c$.

Combining the first and second observation, $p$ divides precisely one of $b,c$

Comment: I hope to remember the contrapositive approach for giving a better touch to such proofs.

Comment: Yes, it can be very helpful! 
Sometimes the statement $\neg Q \implies \neg P$ is more natural to work with than the original $P \implies Q$.  Sometimes the degree is surprisingly!
I should also mention that in the original proof you gave your logic was not really correct.  You made a conclusion about when $p^2 \nmid a$ from an observation that if $p^2 | a$ then $p$ divides at least one of $b,c$ (which we already knew that from $p | a$).

Comment: I made same sort of argument, as your better symbolically expressed one. In fact, mathematical symbolism was absent in mine. May be, this caused confusion which any natural language can bring. My argument was that either $p^2 \mid b$ or $p^2 \mid c$ or $p \mid c, b$; else $p^2 \nmid a$. My argument for either-or was for $p^2$ and not $p$.

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ divides both $b$ and $c$, then $b=pk$ and $c=pq$ for some $k,q \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
Therefore,

$$a=bc=p^2kq$$

which implies $p^2 \mid a$. Contradiction. That means $p$ cannot divide both $a$ and $b$ simultaneously.

Now, since $p \mid a$, we should have $p \mid bc$.

If $p$ doesn't divide one of them, let's say $c$, then $(c,p)=1$. Therefore, $p \mid b$. That means if $p$ doesn't divide one of them, then it must divide the other one.

I used the following theorem from elementary number theory:

$\star$ **Theorem:** If $r \mid st$ and $(r,s)=1$, then $r \mid t$

Proof: Since $(r,s)=1$, there exist $x_0,y_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $rx_0+sy_0=1$

Since $r \mid st$, there exists $z_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $rz_0=st$.

Multiplying the first result by $t$:

$$rx_0t+(st)y_0=t$$
$$rx_0t+(rz_0)y_0=t$$
$$r(x_0t+z_0y_0)=t$$
Therefore,

$$r \mid t$$

Comment: Please help by preventing the post from deletion, by upvoting.